# Is it possible to leverage two inversions into one sentence?

Tags: inversion

I don't have the foggiest idea about the rectitude of my instance, as well as about the viability of the creation of this sort of sentence. If my example is not correct, and if putting two inversions in one sentence is feasible, could I ask one put forward an example?

> Only then did I understand that little did I know.

Comment: Alan, it helps if you phrase your question in simple terms rather than confusing us with references to **the rectitude of my beneath instance**, whatever that might be.

Comment: Maybe "correctness of my example below".

Comment: *Blessed are the pure in heart, for inherit the earth they will.*